# ExtJS 4 textfield inside nested autoEl tags

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to render some input box and labels nested within div's. Problem is html is showing rather than the input. What would be the best way to achieve this?

This will potentially have an unlimited amount of nested div's and input box.

```
{
 xType: 'panel',
 autoEl:[
 {
  tag: 'div', cls:'rule', children: 
  [
   {
   tag: 'div', cls:'condition', children:
    [
    {tag: 'span', html:'Permit'},
    {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'inputname',
    value: 'this is my test',
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
 ],
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This is for an XML editor. This part of the code is where an unlimited number of nested conditions and values needs to be rendered in a form and displayed in indented manner. Currently my solution is just generate the HTML with the nested div's and input then stick it to the html property of a panel. After that I search for each input box and bind my functions. That works OK but I think it would be better if I can put the listeners and or custom components, etc. Then generate the form.

Comment: FYI: Trailing commas before braces like in this line `value: 'this is my test',` or in this `],` will cause some browsers like IE9 to stop executing your code. You should remove all unnecessary commas.

Comment: I took this sample from a much larger test case I was working on and cleaned out most of the stuff to get the basic stuff I was trying to achieve. I'm building this object dynamically in the browser, not just generating a string to eval. So these extra commas will never be an issue to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a form and add input fields to it? You can use any layouts available to the panel in the form. Adding fields to the form on the fly works fairly well. You could also use a controller to bind your functions to the form fields.

Comment: I guess I can do that, but what Im wondering is if its possible to combine nested autoEl tags and components.